# CSS file path doesn't work both on localhost and in text editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

So, I'm working on URL Shortener written in JS using Node.js and Express. I've just finished front end but I have a problem with getting css to work.
My project tree looks like this:

```
public
  css
    main.css
views
  index.html
app.js
```

In my index.html file I have my .css file linked this way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/main.css">
```

and it does work while making the site in Brackets editor, but when I launch localhost server CSS doesn't and I get

```
Cannot GET /public/css/main.css
```

I suppose it has something to do with my static path declared in app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

because when I change the path in index.html to `/css/main.css` everything works on localhost but then my local text editor (Brackets) can't see that css file.
What should I do to make it work both during development in text editor and on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways ( probably more ) :

**Option 1**

Go with your browser for debugging your application ( use only your app to see the modifications and not the brackets editor )

**Option 2**

Set your `href=""` attribute to a static location, e.g. `href="localhost:8080/css/main.css"`. Then ( probably ) when you run your editor and the app simultaneously, you will get the same CSS file on both sides.

**Option 3**

Add another line of stylesheet to load them both.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">
```

The most common way to solve this problem, usually is **Option 1**, so you can just don't bother about bracket's internal browser and figure out a combination with [live-reload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload) module that will duplicate the extras that you get from your editor.

Comment: Option 1 - is the easiest one, but unfortunately Brackets has absolutely the best live preview on the market and there is no way that I would give up on this.
Option 2 - does not work, localhost server is still searching for `main.css` in `/public` just like the static path tells it to.
Option 3 - well, it does work. 
Thanks for help : )

Answer (score 0):

browser sends a get request to fetch a CSS file, you can add the following code snippet in you code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var query = url.parse(req.url, true)
var pathname = query.pathname
var filepath = "./public/"

if(fs.existsSync(filepath+pathname)){
    res.end(fs.readFileSync(filepath+pathname));
}
```

**now in the html page** :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
```

**Explained** :

the *browser* will send a **GET** request for `css/main.css`
and the `pathname` will be then `css/main.css`
`filepath` is *declared* as `./public/`

`filepath + pathname` will be `./public/css/main.css`

`fs.existsSync` will return `true` and write the *data* in *response*.

becauase you `filepath` is `./public/`  only files under *public* directory can be send in this method so your *app.js/ file is **safe**.

I have written this in *synchronus* manner using **Sync** functions you can do it using *asynchronus* manner too.

**hope this helps**